# Which VPS providers are the most popular or notable for hosting bitcoind instances?

Tags: bitcoind, services, server, hosting

A lot of people wanting to create their own service communicating with a bitcoind instance use virtual servers for hosting due to the low associated costs. Which service providers are the most popular and notable in this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BitVPS](http://www.bitvps.com/) offers a VPS with a pre-installed and synced bitcoind, and of course they accept payment in Bitcoin.  Email the owner (james@bitvps.com) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I would not trust any preloaded blockchain, or a precompiled bitcoind for that matter. Bitronic Technologies offers [VPS](http://www.bitronictech.net/vps-hosting.php) that can run almost any major flavor of linux via Xen PV and you can most certainly compile/install bitcoind on them.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.yokucloud.com

YOKU Cloud is a bitcoin supported hosting provider.

Comment: It seems like the cheapest plan they offer is $20 a month, which isn't amazing. They do allow you to pay for hosting in bitcoin, though I don't think that's what ThePiachu meant.